# Warning 1 Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'string'

Tags: c#, winforms

I read from a text file . in that text file a line is with YES or NO (yes if it's correct, no if it's not)

I used at the beginning `answer.Tag = "NO;"` then when I press a button it goes `answer.Tag = "YES";`

I have a verify button which does

```
if (answer[0].Tag == "bla bla" && answer[1].Tag== "blabla2")
{
    MessageBox.Show("They Match");
}
else 
    MessageBox.Show("They don't");
```

Then I have this problem :  Warning 1 Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'string'

I don't know why it doesn't do the comparison . It skips to else

Comment: I have modified the double equal signs. They were not my problem. :)

Comment: Check the answer of Alex!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Possible unintended reference comparison` is this one:

```
answer[1].Tag == "blabla2"
```

The `Tag` is an `object`, you are allowed to compare it to `"blabla2"` because `string` is a reference type. The compiler is "casting" your `string` to `object` and is performing a reference comparison (which will evaluate to `false` since they are not the same object).

To fix this, you have to cast `Tag` before checking. Together with the fix I mentioned above, your code would become

```
if (answer[0].Tag.ToString() == "bla bla" && answer[1].Tag.ToString() == "blabla2")
{
    MessageBox.Show("They Match");
}
else 
    MessageBox.Show("They don't");
```

Comment: I already defined answer.tag as a string. if I put again .tostring() it's like a double transformation..

Comment: I don't know who upvoted whis. `This will assign "bla bla" to answer[0].Tag and subsequently evaluate to true` are you sure?

Comment: Where does he assign?! He uses double equals sign.

Comment: OP edited the code in the question to fix the assignment operation, so my remark about it is no longer relevant.

Comment: @Alex Even if OP have not edited the question your statement is **wrong**

Answer (score 0):

correction of your code:

```
if (answer[0].Tag == "bla bla" && answer[1].Tag== "blabla2")
{
    MessageBox.Show("They Match");
}
else 
    MessageBox.Show("They don't");
```

here specifically in your if condition:

```
if (answer[0].Tag **==** "bla bla" && answer[1].Tag== "blabla2")
```

should be 2 equals signs, not one

Comment: You're right, but that's not the cause for warning. I suspect OP have correct code, else he'd get compile time error

Comment: Tag is an object, he has to call `ToString` for evaluation. You're right about the equals sign.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: there's no compile time error if you put an assignment instead of equality operator - it'll perform the assignment and return an unexpected result!

Comment: I tried how you did, and I have more errors now. errors like ";expected" after each condition in that if .

Comment: You'll have to remove the asterixes!

Comment: @DanPuzey Are you sure? You're right only when talking about `Boolean` that's not the case here

Comment: not asterix :)) I know that . but I already used answer.tag = a string

Comment: I made the correction in the 1st block of code. the 2nd block highlights (well, the editor tried to but I guess it didn't do it!) with the astrix the part im specifically referring to. if you copy and paste the first block, it will work

Answer (score 0):

Usually `Tag` property will be of type `Object`, so I assume it is of type `Object`. `==` operator with `System.Object` work as reference comparison (meaning references of the instances are compared than value).

To fix it just introduce a cast  to string.

```
if ((string)answer[0].Tag == "bla bla" && (string)answer[1].Tag== "blabla2")
{
    MessageBox.Show("They Match");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("They don't");
}
```

Comment: Look at Alex's answer, you're right about the double equals sign but he has to call `ToString` on the Tag-property as it is an object and not a string.

Comment: and casting or `ToString()` is unnecessary. .ToString() is the default return of an object

Comment: @Abbas What's there with Alex's answer? It is wrong with this statement `This will assign "bla bla" to answer[0].Tag and subsequently evaluate to true`

Comment: @Franck It is **required** else there will be a reference comparison. That's what the question is about.

Comment: I'm not talking about the assignment, it's about having an object being evaluated to a string. @Franck Try comparing the value of the Tag-property of a WinForms control to a string, won't work, even if the value IS a string.

Comment: @Abbas Yup, you can use `ToString` or else just cast to `string` if you're sure that instance is `string`. :)